# Using jQuery $ajax, responses are sometimes being sent or tied to the wrong GET calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm using jQuery $ajax. I'm sending three queries to an acting "server" that's actually a board within a piece of industrial equipment.

They're querying XML data and the response is displaying in a web browser.

It's working good most of the time, but sometimes the responses become unsynchronized.

Here's what I'm passing.

Query - GET:Device_AB>Unit
URL - aaaaaaaaaa/device.xml?query=GET%3ADevice_AB%3EUnit&_=1419001010182

Query - GET:Device_AB>Device1>CD>EFG
URL - aaaaaaaaaa/device.xml?query=GET%3ADevide_AB%3EDevice1%3ECD%3EEFG&_=1419000598786

Query - GET:Device_AB>Unit>Status
URL - aaaaaaaaaa/device.xml?query=GET%3ADevice_AB%3EUnit%3EStatus&_=1419002064896

What's happening is that instead of receiving the correct response to the first GET which should be the contents within the Unit(1st) XML tag, the communication is going out of synchronization and the response is from the EFG(2nd) XML tag or the Status(3rd) XML tag. The same happens to the GET query for the contents of the Status XML tag. The suffix on the end of the URL is unique every time. Does anyone know why the response is not associating itself with the correct call? I am repeating the call to all three within about half a second so the data on the screen updates continuously. The javascript is quite involved and covers several pages. I believe the JavaScript is fine. It's pretty standard and is working on other industrial equipment without synch loss. It seems to me that as long as the call is going out correctly, the synchronization problem with the response is likely at the server. Without understanding how the server processes and returns the data, my question is more of a theoretical one. How does the server know which GET to send the response back to?, or in other words, how does the server tie the response to the correct GET call?

There are many ajax sections among several javascript pages, but I believe this is the pertinent part for this application. There's much more to it, but I don't really want to chop it apart if I don't have to. I'm fairly convinced that the problem is server side.

```
    this.ajaxParameters = {

        type: "GET",

        url: this.url,

        data: {query:"GET:"+this.xmlPath},

        dataType: (self.groupMode === true) ? "xml" : "text",

        timeout: 5000,

        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {

            self.parseResponse(data);

        },

        error: function() {

            $("#errorfield").text("no communication");

        },

        complete: function() {

            self.ajaxInProgress = 0;

        }

    };
```

Comment: Understand the question but need to see the actual javascript/jQuery in order to answer.

Comment: ajax requests are not instant, the duration varies from request to request. sometimes, your second and third requests may finish faster than your first, which is what causes the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @KevinB, this is not a duplicate of that question. The scenario is different.

Comment: then vote to re-open. i disagree. In both cases the problem is n number of ajax requests are sent and they are received in a different order than they were sent.

Comment: How do I vote to re-open?

Comment: @KevinB. Hi Kevin - So if I'm understanding you correctly, the responses come chronologically regardless of the actual GET string sent even If I'm adding a unique identifier at the end of each string. Sound right?

Comment: Correct, they come back in the order that the server finishes building the response. @Roamer-1888 sorry, didn't realize you don't have enough rep. requires 3000 :/

Comment: Thanks Kevin B!, and thanks Roamer-1888 for taking a look!

Comment: @RobbyCoder, thanks for the code but it's not enough. I need to see more of `self` and how the request triplets are made. (I used to work for a process control company so am fairly familiar with this kind of application).

Comment: BTW, even if there is a server-side issue, a client-side solution should be possible. And it's absolutely nothing like any of the answers provided to the would-be duplicate question.